# EMC issue on 6 layer PCB design

Tags: pcb, emc, emissions

I have EMC issue and there is spike at 64 MHz on my 6 layer PCB design. I have used many decoupling capacitors and ferrite beads according to the datasheet. Is there any cad tool to measure on which part of the PCB, there is the high emission and by changing the capacitor and ferrite bead to see what happen to the electromagnetic behaviour to optimze and select the best bypass capacitor value and ferrite beads?

Comment: If you have an emissions issue it is more likely to be due to poor layout than schematic.

Comment: 64 MHz might be on the edge here, but it's not outside of reason to try to add stray inductance from your layout into your schematic and see if anything close to 64 MHz pops up.

Comment: tools will give only guidelines, they can't find the emission.

Comment: If the spike is consistent, I would be suspicious of anywhere there is a clock signal of a power of two output frequency (4MHz, 8MHz, 16MHz, 32MHz); I have seen where such signals are buffered with multiple outputs available and some outputs not terminated; I have seen 8th harmonic spikes at significant energy in these scenarios.

Comment: @ashkan you'll need to define what your 'issue' is and post some pics of the layout and some scope pictures, also state where the ground is located for the scope trace

Comment: The emission is related to the clock frequency after PLL frequency devision. First I used ferrite beads on the signal traces to MCU. but it is strange when I removed the ferrites it showed better behavior on EMC part without phase shifting. I think maybe the reason is that without the ferrite MCU can sink more current from power plane. I tested the board with reducing the 4MHz to 1MHz data acquisition and better behavior is observed but still there is 8 dbuv higher than the standard on 64 MHz.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of CAD tools exist to check your design for EMC issues. Hyperlynx is one I've used my self, I know that OrCAD has some built in, as did PADS last time I looked at it. There was talk of Altium having something, but I think that was more signal integrity rather than EMC emission related.

You seem fixed on it being a schematic issue. Most EMC design methods are to do with layout, not schematic entry. Without seeing your layout we can't judge, but the usual suspects are:

- Crossing of power planes
- Inadequate reference planes
- Unbalanced signal lines
- No proper termination on signal lines
- Improper decoupling capacitor values or placement

If you have checked all these, then check your PCB for antenna. There are lots of ways to accidentally create one, though 64MHz is quite a low frequency for one.

Don't forget that a square wave produces a lot a frequencies. It is not one frequency, as a square wave can't exist in the real world on it's own, it's actually made up of lots of sin-waves to give the required frequency.

If it is a signal line which is causing this emission, it is due to high currents down a trace. To fix this, you can usually reduce your source current driver from whatever source you are using, or, if that is not an option, a series termination resistor at the required end will do the job. Simulate the signal for signal integrity and it will highlight what is required.

Comment: If I were to guess--and I'm assuming you have at least one power/ground plane, most likely two in a 6-layer board--I'd guess you've split up those planes and then run high-speed or high-current traces over the splits.  This is in my experience one of the most common EMC mistakes.  In general, people are careful about how signal traces are routed, but tend to assume return paths will just sort themselves out.

Comment: Altium was in talks with a company that had an FEM solver. Zuken, however, decided it would be a shame if someone were to acquire said company. Now the FEM solver ships with their Lightning package. It’s pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel there is any cad tool to identify, which trace will have high emissions. If there is a spike at 64MHz then this could be because of your clock frequency if 16 or 32KHz or MHz. Check in your PCB the traces for these clock signal and reduce the length of your traces since these traces behaves as antenna for emissions. Or you can use a decoupling capacitor of 100nF at the clock signal source.

Comment: Lots of CAD tools exist which can spot EMC issues. PADs has one built in (if you pay extra), OrCAD has one built it. Hyperlynx is a good suite which I believe can be bought stand alone. Also, teh 64MHz signal just means that there's a 64MHz antenna on the PCB. NOT that there's a 64MHz signal causing the issue.